# Como evitar repetição do código html?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, include

Boa noite, Pessoal. É o o seguinte, estou usando o bootstrap e gostaria de saber como eu evito de repetir os mesmos códigos em todas as paginas, pois o header e o footer são os mesmos, isso deixaria o código mais legivel, andei pesquisando e vi que se deveria usar o Include do PHP, mas não sei como usar, me ajudem, por favor. Grato ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A primeira coisa a se fazer é separar seu website em 3 arquivos.

- header.html
- conteudo.php
- footer.html

Como pode perceber no header terá o cabeçalho e no footer o rodapé.

Então no `conteudo.php` você fará os includes, o `header.html` no início do código e `footer.html` no fim, segue exemplo:

```
<?php include 'header.html'; ?>

<h1>Nome da pagina</h1>

<?php  include 'footer.html'; ?>
```

E assim para todas páginas que queira reaproveitar o cabeçalho e rodapé.

obs. Os arquivos que irão ser incluídos não necessariamente precisam ser PHP, somente onde se quer incluir é necessário PHP.

Comment: Caso você não queira utilizar arquivos .php no seu site, dá  para fazer isso utilizando jQuery.

Comment: Perfeito @Ricardo

Comment: Fiz como vc falou, mas ainda não funciona, tipo, eu coloquei todo o html na pagina, certinho, ai eu tiro todo o código da Navbar e jogo num documento separado, quando eu dou o include ele n mostra a navbar.

Comment: Consegui resolver, eu não havia colocado a extensão da pagina index como php.

Comment: @TiagoSilveira muito bom :) Lembrando que você pode ter quantos includes quiser, por exemplo também separar um menu lateral

Answer (score 3):

Basta salvar a header e o footer em arquivos separados por ex header.php e footer.php

depois disso na sua pagina principal no lugar do header e do footer vc faz um include

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
```

faz a mesma coisa no lugar do footer

```
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode salvar em arquivos diferentes. Isso deixa o código mais limpo, legível e mais rápido em caso de posteriores edições, claro que se usado de maneira correta. Um belo exemplo é se todas as paginas possuem o mesmo rodapé e você precisa alterar uma informação que esta presente nele, sem separar os arquivos você teria que editar em todos, dando mais trabalho. 
Segue abaixo um exemplo de um index, fragmentado em vários arquivos:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
include("inclusoes/cabecalho.php");
if(isset($_GET['sair']) && $_GET['sair']== true){
    unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
    }
 ?>
<body>
<header id="header"><!--header-->
<?php include_once("inclusoes/menu.php");?>
</header>
<!--/header-->
<?php
if(!isset($categoria)|| $categoria==""){
 include_once("inclusoes/inicio.php");
}
else if(isset($categoria) && $categoria!=""){
    if(file_exists("inclusoes/$categoria.php")){
     include_once("inclusoes/$categoria.php");
    }
    else{
         include_once("404.php");   
        }
    }
 ?>
<?php include_once("inclusoes/rodape.php");?>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que isso lhe ajude a compreender. 
Lembrando que o **include_once** tem a garantia que o arquivo não será incluído novamente se ele já foi incluído antes.

Comment: Mas e ai como deve ser a estrutura dos aquivos que estarão separados? muda alguma coisa devido ao fato de eu uso o bootstrap?

Comment: não compreendi sua dúvida...  Mas se eu entendi, não muda nao, porque com os includes no final o arquivo vai ser o mesmo, ele só esta dividido. Como no meu exemplo ali, no meu cabeçalho estao todos os meus links do bootstrap, css, js e outros... Ele esta separado somente, mas com o include, quando a pagina for carregada se torna somente um, compreende?